# What does "warning: section .bss: alignment 2**32 not representable" mean in GNU Assembler?

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-alignment, gnu-assembler

Assembling the x86 assembly code produced by my compiler using the version of GNU Assembler that comes with MinGW-w64 produces the following warning:

```
E:/MinGW32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: analogClockForWindows.exe: warning: section .bss: alignment 2**32 not representable
```

What does that mean? What puzzles me the most is that the assembly code does not mention `.bss` at all.
I do not know if it is related, but the version of GNU Assembler that comes with CygWin and one that comes with TDM-GCC both refuse to even assemble my code, and give a ton of error messages.
The assembly code that is produced by my compiler is available here: https://github.com/FlatAssembler/ArithmeticExpressionCompiler/files/6446315/analogClockForWindows.s.zip

EDIT: I was simply using `gcc -o analogClockForWindows analogClockForWindows.s` to compile the assembly code produced by [my compiler](https://flatassembler.github.io/compiler.html).

UPDATE: I think this is the minimal example that triggers that warning:

```
.text
.comm   output,7360,32
.global _main
_main:
movl    $0, %eax
ret
```

Comment: It probably means that you used `.align 32`, and it was interpreted as `.p2align` (power-of-2) instead of  `.balign` (byte).  Never use the ambiguous `.align` directive.  I'm not interested enough to download and unzip code to look at it, if you can't be bothered to put a [mcve] into the question.

Comment: @PeterCordes Nope, the assembly code does not mention `.align` at all. Sorry, I know very little about assembly, so I cannot produce a minimal reproducible example. If I knew the nuts and bolts of the assembly language, I would not be asking this question.

Comment: What is "your compiler", then?  If you don't know much about assembly, trying to write your own compiler might not be a good first step.  Is that what you're doing?

Comment: The error is from the linker, not the assembler.  Please post the exact commands you use to assemble and link.

Comment: @NateEldredge I was simply using `gcc -o analogClockForWindows analogClockForWindows.s` to compile the assembly code produced by my compiler.

Comment: And is your `gcc` able to compile and run simple C programs?

Comment: Also, that's an `ld` error, not `as`.  So your code does assemble, but then `ld` chokes on the `.obj` created by GAS?  Probably worth looking at the `.obj` with some tools like a PE/COFF equivalent of `readelf`.

Comment: @NateEldredge The GCC is able to compile and run C programs, I compiled Duktape using it, to run the compiler I have written in JavaScript in Duktape.

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't be able to create a [mcve].  All you need is a `.s` file that produces that error when you run GCC on it.  It doesn't have to also be a useful program, so just start by removing half the lines and see if the error still happens, etc.  (https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/).  That should get it down to something you can copy/paste into a code block here.

Comment: @PeterCordes OK, I will try that.

Comment: Do you use `.comm` or `.lcomm` at all for global variables?  That's the other way to create symbols in the BSS.  (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Comm.html)

Comment: @PeterCordes I am using `.comm` to create global variables, as I have seem GCC doing that. I do not know what is BSS.

Comment: You shouldn't even need global variables for evaluating an expression.  Just reserve some stack space if you run out of x87 stack registers.  Or I guess you're taking input from global vars instead of stack args or register args :/

Comment: @PeterCordes I think I have found the minimal example, and I included it in the question. So, why does not this warning occur on Linux (where GCC outputs exactly the same code), but it occurs on Windows?

Comment: Pretty obviously for the same reason as `.align`: the 3rd arg is treated as a power-of-2 alignment on this target, but as a byte value for x86-elf-linux.

Comment: @PeterCordes So, what happens if I do not fix that? The program seems to work in spite of that somehow.

Comment: You just said it *doesn't* work on Windows, that's the whole point of this question, right?  So you're getting 32-byte alignment on Linux which works, but 2^32 (4GiB) alignment on Windows which doesn't.

Comment: @PeterCordes But my program does run on WIndows, it just produces a warning during linking. That is a warning, not an error.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Then probably it ignores the requested alignment and you get some default, maybe 4, 8, or 16 bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Comm.html#Comm

> When using ELF or (as a GNU extension) PE, the .comm directive takes an optional third argument. This is the desired alignment of the symbol, specified for ELF as a byte boundary (for example, an alignment of 16 means that the least significant 4 bits of the address should be zero), and for PE as a power of two (for example, an alignment of 5 means aligned to a 32-byte boundary).

ELF is the executable format used on Linux, and PE is on Windows.  So for ELF (Linux), `.comm output,7360,32` requests that `output` be aligned to a 32-byte boundary, which is fine.  But for PE (Windows), the same directive is interpreted as asking for `2**32` byte alignment, which is impossible.  On Windows you should instead write `.comm output,7360,5`.

I don't know why these are different; probably for compatibility with other different assemblers.

You'll probably need to add a flag to your compiler to select between Windows and Linux so that the correct directive can be output for each case.

Comment: `.comm` apparently has a reasonable default for alignment, size up to 16 on ELF.  (But apparently only up to 4 on PE).  Still, you only need to write it once; the fact that the current compiler uses tons of instructions that store/reload to that `[disp32]` absolute address is a big missed optimization for code-size vs. a stack temporary.

Answer (score 4):

It could mean that you used `.align 32`, and it was interpreted as `.p2align` (power-of-2) instead of  `.balign` (byte).

**Never use the ambiguous [`.align`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Align.html) directive** when targeting GAS, which supports unambiguous directives.

---

In your case, the **alignment is coming in the 3rd arg to `.comm`** to define a global variable in the BSS.  Like `.align`, the interpretation is target-dependent, and when assembling for Windows, that means you're asking it to align by `2**32` (or 4GiB), which `ld` doesn't handle.

(When assembling for i386-elf-linux, it means align by 32, `2**5`, which works as intended.)

As documented in [the GAS manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Comm.html):

> When using ELF or (as a GNU extension) PE, the .comm directive takes an optional third argument. This is the desired alignment of the symbol, specified **for ELF as a byte boundary** (for example, an alignment of 16 means that the least significant 4 bits of the address should be zero), and **for PE as a power of two** (for example, an alignment of 5 means aligned to a 32-byte boundary).
>
> The alignment must be an absolute expression, and it must be a power of two. If ld allocates uninitialized memory for the common symbol, it will use the alignment when placing the symbol.
>
> If no alignment is specified, as will set the alignment to the largest power of two less than or equal to the size of the symbol, up to a maximum of 16 on ELF, or the default section alignment of 4 on PE

Unfortunately there's no portable unambiguous syntax way to use it.  You could just omit that optional 3rd arg and use the default alignment.

Or you could instead use a `.bss` directive to switch to the BSS section and use `.space` to reserve space after a `label:`.

**Or just don't use any global vars, and leave the result in `st0`.**  You don't need any to eval an expression, if you take args on the stack instead of globals.  At most you could use stack space, if you run out of x87 registers.  Or you could reference globals but leave the definitions up to other compilation units (e.g. a caller that does input/output.)

Also, does `result` really need to be 7360 bytes?  Your compiler (https://flatassembler.github.io/compiler.html) only ever uses `[result]`, not `[result + reg]` or `+ constant`